# Scala case class, can't override constructor parameter

Tags: scala, constructor, case-class

I have this case class:

```
 case class MyCaseClass(left:Long, right: Long = Option[Long], operator: Operator = Option[Operator]){

    def inRange(outer: Long) = outer >= left && outer <= right
  }
```

This is how I try to instantiate it:

```
val instance = MyCaseClass(leftValue)
```

But I get a compilation error:

> Unspecified value parameters right, operator

What does this error mean? I just want to have two constructors for a case class: one with three params and one with one param.

This works (as Ende Neu suggested):

```
case class MyCaseClass(left:Long, right: Option[Long] = None, operator: Option[Operator] = None)
```

The problem is that I have to wrap `right` and `operator` in an `Option`.  The below allows you to avoid `Option` wrapping for the `right` and `operator` parameters (see answer for more details):

```
object MyCaseClass {
  def apply(left: Long, right: Long, operator: Operator) = new MyCaseClass(left, Option(right), Option(operator))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing a default value, you are passing a type, if you want to pass default parameters you have to specify some value:

```
scala>  case class Operator(operation: String)
defined class Operator

scala>   case class MyCaseClass(left:Long, right: Long = 0L, operator: Operator = Operator("+")){
      |     def inRange(outer: Long) = outer >= left && outer <= right
      |   }
defined class MyCaseClass

scala>   val instance = MyCaseClass(10L)
instance: MyCaseClass = MyCaseClass(10,0,Operator(+))
```

If you want to wrap them in `Option` you have to declare them so:

```
 case class MyCaseClass(left:Long, right: Option[Long] = None, operator: Option[Operator] = None)
```

Where I used `None` as value, you could use also `Some` and pass some default value to them.

If you don't want the user to create a full object using options, create a companion object and define a new apply method:

```
case class Operator(operation: String)

object MyCaseClass {
  def apply(left: Long, right: Long, operator: Operator) = new MyCaseClass(left, Option(right), Option(operator))
}

case class MyCaseClass(left:Long, right: Option[Long] = None, operator: Option[Operator] = None)
```

You can now construct an object in different ways:

```
MycaseClass(10L)
MycaseClass(10L, Option(10L), Option(Operator("+"))
MycaseClass(10L, 20L, Operator("+"))
```

Comment: Hi, I works with default values. I would like to set null/nothing/None (not sure what is right :( ). I want to explicitly set two non-mandatory params to "absent values". Like in java - if i try to use thme, I'll get NullPointerException. When I use right: Option[Long] = None, compiler complains in method  "inRange", I can't use right as Long, since it's an option

Comment: Then you want to avoid null, make the right and operator field as `Option` and pass `None` as default, in Scala null have meaning only when dealing with Java code, you almost always want to use `Option`.

Comment: Yes, I undertand, the problem is that I can create instance using  MyCaseClass(10L) and MyCaseClass(10L, Option(20L), Option(operatorInstace)). My API user should not care about Option wrapping. I don't want to push option to high level. I want to push oveloaded constructors: (Long) and (Long, Long, Operator)

Comment: Yes, you have to define the companyon object **and** the case class. Now if you pass in only the `left` parameter the other two will be `None` because the apply method of the case class will be called, if you pass in all three without option the apply method of the companion object will be called.

Comment: I've deleted 2 comments, solution work. Thanks for helping study Scala. It's cool!